# *nix One-Liner: Recursively find files by extension, and copy them to a new directory named for the extension

Tags: linux, command-line, unix

Given many directories/sub-directories containing many different file types (csv, txt, jpg, etc.), what command will search each directory recursively and copy files out into a new top-level directory named after each extension.

Is there a way to accomplish this with a one-liner?

Comment: The command you need called `find`. You can construct it as one-liner

Comment: Why would it have to be on one line?

Comment: I'd imagine that they want a command to run via SSH or something where a script won't necessarily exist on the destination system.

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

The following command will list all files in the current directory (`.`) and move them into directories named after their extensions in `./OUTPUT`:

```
for file in $(find . -type f) ; do EXTENSION=$(echo "$file" |sed 's/.*\.//g') ; rsync -av $file ./OUTPUT/$EXTENSION/ ; done
```

Before running the above command, you will need to:

- Create the directory OUTPUT in the current directory (`mkdir OUTPUT`)
- Ensure that there are no files with matching names in any of the subdirectories

### Explanation

Firstly, the loop assigns the variable `file` with a file from the output of `find . -type f`. Example output of the `find` command is below:

```
./a/myfile1.zip
./a/b/adoc1.txt
./a/b/adoc2.txt
./a/b/adoc3.txt
./a/b/adoc4.txt
./a/myfile3.zip
./a/myfile4.zip
./a/myfile2.zip
```

The variable `EXTENSION` is created and its value is the `file` variable with everything up to the last full-stop stripped out. So `./a/myfile1.zip` would become `zip`.

The file is then synced (with verbosity, `v`) to a directory within `OUTPUT` named after the file extension.

An example of my file tree after running this command on some test:

```
./a
./a/b
./a/b/adoc1.txt
./a/b/adoc2.txt
./a/b/adoc3.txt
./a/b/adoc4.txt
./a/b/c
./a/myfile1.zip
./a/myfile2.zip
./a/myfile3.zip
./a/myfile4.zip
./b
./b/c
./b/c/d
./b/c/file1.txt
./b/c/file2.txt
./b/c/file3.txt
./b/c/file4.txt
./c
./c/d
./c/d/e
./c/d/e/afile1.rar
./c/d/e/afile2.rar
./c/d/e/afile3.rar
./c/d/e/afile4.rar
./OUTPUT
./OUTPUT/rar
./OUTPUT/rar/afile1.rar
./OUTPUT/rar/afile2.rar
./OUTPUT/rar/afile3.rar
./OUTPUT/rar/afile4.rar
./OUTPUT/txt
./OUTPUT/txt/adoc1.txt
./OUTPUT/txt/adoc2.txt
./OUTPUT/txt/adoc3.txt
./OUTPUT/txt/adoc4.txt
./OUTPUT/txt/file1.txt
./OUTPUT/txt/file2.txt
./OUTPUT/txt/file3.txt
./OUTPUT/txt/file4.txt
./OUTPUT/zip
./OUTPUT/zip/myfile1.zip
./OUTPUT/zip/myfile2.zip
./OUTPUT/zip/myfile3.zip
./OUTPUT/zip/myfile4.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done very simply with *find*, as correctly suggested by Alex: assuming the directory to scan for files is */path1/to/some/dir*, and you want the files moved to */path2/to/other/dir/txt* and so on,

```
find /path1/some/dir -type f -exec bash -c 'MYDIR=/path2/to/other/dir${0##*.}; [ -d $MYDIR ] && mv $0 $MYDIR  || mv $0 /path3/to/miscellanea' {} \;
```

This command first finds all files (*-type f*) contained within the directory */path1/to/some/dir* and all of its subdirectories, then passes the name of each such file (*{}*) to a small bash two-liner, which first extracts the extension from the file name (referred to as *$0* inside bash) and assigns it to the local shell variable *MYDIR*, then **tests** for the existence of a suitable directory (if there is no such directory, then maybe we made a mistake), and if the directory exists (*&& ...*) it moves the file in the appropriate directory, otherwise (*||...*) it places the file in a default place, */path3/to/miscellanea*.

The above assumes you already have created the necessary directories, */path2/to/other/dir/txt* and so on. If instead you want to create them on the go, you will have to modify the above as:

```
find /path1/some/dir -type f -exec bash -c 'MYDIR=/path2/to/other/dir/${0##*.}; mkdir -p $MYDIR && mv $0 $MYDIR' {} \;
```